# Proving degree $n$ have at last $n$ roots in $F_q[X]$

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, finite-fields

How to prove that in $F_{q}[X]$ of degree $n$, have $n$ roots?

Comment: Please tell us what you've tried and where you are stuck so we can give you more focused help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A field (finite or not) is always an integral domain, hence assuming that $\xi$ is a root of $p(x)=a_n x^n+\ldots+a_0$, then $p(x)=(x-\xi)q(x)$, where the degree of $q(x)$ is just the degree of $p(x)$ minus one. By induction, the number of the roots cannot exceed the degree.

Comment: seem like incomplète proof!!

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: proof that the factorization is unique

Comment: If $\mathbb{K}$ is a field, then $\mathbb{K}[x]$ is a UFD.

Comment: ok thanks :) Jack

Comment: The argument did not use the fact that the ring is a domain (which is necessary).